# GWT Module is unloading randomly

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT project I have been working on for several months.  I am using the GWT Development Mode with Chrome 34.0.1847.131 m and Eclipse EE Indigo with GWT 2.5.0.  All of the sudden is started failing to load sometimes with no errors.  After some investigation, I found the only difference is this second line:

```
[INFO] [mypackage.MyClass] - Module mypackage.MyClass has been loaded
[INFO] [mypackage.MyClass] - Unloading module mypackage.MyClass (mypackage.MyClass)
```

There is about 150ms between the load and unload.  This started failing randomly yesterday.  Prior to that it always ran fine.  It's strange, I will clear my cache and restart the browser and it works fine for a while, then it just stops working again.  How do I get GWT to output the real problem?  I put -logLevel=DEBUG but that did not add any more logs to it.

Comment: +1 Same here. Started a week ago. Still haven't found a solution.

Comment: Could be an incompatibility between Chrome and the DevMode plugin. Chrome will soon stop supporting DevMode anyway, so try switching to SuperDevMode.

Comment: **Don't** use Chrome in DevMode due to bug in Chrome itself. Try wiht Firefox and Let me know whether the problem is still exists or not.

Comment: @Braj The GWT plugin only supports Firefox up to v24 (v29 is the current one). So unless you have an outdated browser, this isn't really an alternative.

Comment: However, if you want to use FF, you can download a portable version (v24) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox,%20Portable%20Edition%2024.0/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT project's advice to me was to just use SuperDevMode, which worked for a little while.  I ended up deleting all of the GWT cache after SuperDevMode was not rebuilding properly...then I couldn't get it to work at all.  I switched back to Chrome's DevMode and it has worked ever since.  I'm not sure if there was a chrome update or if deleting all of my gwt compiled files fixed it.